# Serialization Fails with XmlSchemaSet

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I am developing C Sharp application. I am trying to put a Object in Membase (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couchbase_Server) for caching.

It fails when the Object have XmlSchemaSet type field. If I remove XmlSchemaSet type field from Object, then it stores Object in Membase.

How can I put Object in Membase which have XmlSchemaSet type field? Please suggest...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace Serialization
{
    [Serializable]
    public class DataObject
    {
        private string folder = "F1";
    private XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = null;
        public string Folder
        {
            get
            {
                return this.folder;
            }
            set
            {
                this.folder = value;
            }
        }

        public XmlSchemaSet SchemaSet
        {
            get
            {
                return schemaSet;
            }

            set
            {
                this.schemaSet = value;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the `SchemaSet` property to be serialized as well or ignored? Do you need it in the output XML file or just inside your object? Could you please specify what kind of error you get when it "fails".

Comment: Hi Andrei, As of now the object is HashTable in IIS memory....But due to IIS recyling I need to reload it again..

So I want to put object in some Cache (Membase) outside of IIS so that IIS recycling will not affect it...

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on there, if the problem lyes in the `XmlSchemaSet` type or not. What you could try is use a `List<XmlSchema>` instead of `XmlSchemaSet`. Then you can add a [`XmlArrayAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).